How to change the value of one variable so that another variable gets changed too(Python)
I have a variable (a) that is too long. To fix that problem, I want to create another variable (b). Now I am working with (b) because it is short but (a) has to change too. So I have to somehow bind one variable to another so that if one variable changes, the other changes too.
Here is an example:
self.ids["%s" % dayId].background_color = 1


if self.ids["%s" % dayId].background_color == 1:
    self.ids["%s" % dayId].background_color = 0
elif self.ids["%s" % dayId].background_color == 0:
    self.ids["%s" % dayId].background_color = 1

#All of the code above is too long!

Now I have to assign  self.ids["%s" % dayId].background_color  to another variable for cosmetic reasons. Maybe a dictionary approach?

There's nothing inherently wrong with long variable names -- they're often more readable than shorter variable names.

That does not answer my question. I have a long if elif else structure and it is very ugly and takes up much space

You could use a dictionary instead of a long if-elif cascade.


Is "%s" % dayId really necessary? If dayId is an int and self.ids a dict of strings, you should harmonise that to use the same data types to avoid this casting. Also, explicit casting would be more comprehensible: str(dayId).

Condense this entire if..else to:
self.ids[dayId].background_color = int(not self.ids[dayId].background_color)

Use bools instead of ints to even get rid of the int call.


If you still want to "abbreviate variables", at best you can do:
day = self.ids["%s" % dayId]

if day.background_color == 1:
    day.background_color = 0
...

You can't assign self.ids["%s" % dayId].background_color to a variable, since assigning to that afterwards won't change the self.ids["%s" % dayId] object (as you've probably already figured out).
Perhaps the better approach there is to give the self.ids["%s" % dayId] object a method to do all that internally to begin with:
self.ids["%s" % dayId].flip_background_color()




Yes it is necessary, it is a dynamic string means there are diffrent keywords I have to enter to use it multiple times for the same purpose.


My code is much bigger. I just shortened it to give you guys an optimal environment to think about the problem. Thanks though for trying to find other mistakes that I have not asked for.


Thanks for Trying your best to show me abbreviations. My only concern with Python is that sometimes there is unnecessary bulk and repetition

Rarely. If you write pythonic code, you rarely have these kinds of “problems”. I’ve shown you all the ways your code is unpythonic…

I think you still don't get that the code I have shown is just for understanding the problem better. But okay, thanks

Well, I get that, but I can only respond to what you actually show. And I’ve already reduced your 4 repetitive lines to one line. If you applied the same kind of techniques to your entire codebase, I’m pretty sure you could improve it a bit.
